# R convert all rows to strings

Tags: string, r, dataframe

I need to convert all rows of a dataframe to strings.

Here's a sample data:

```
1.12331,4.331123,4.12335435,1,"asd"
1.123453345,5.654456,4.889999,1.45456,"qwe"
2.00098,5.5445,4.768799,1.999999,"ttre"
```

I read this data into R, got a dataframe.

```
td<-read.table("test.csv", sep=',')
```

When I run `apply(td, 2, as.character)` on this data, I got

```
    V1       V2       V3       V4       V5    
[1,] "1.1233" "4.3311" "4.1234" "1.0000" "asd" 
[2,] "1.1235" "5.6545" "4.8900" "1.4546" "qwe" 
[3,] "2.0010" "5.5445" "4.7688" "2.0000" "ttre"
```

But when I do the same only on numeric columns, I got the different result:

```
apply(td[,1:4], 2, as.character)

     V1            V2         V3           V4        
[1,] "1.12331"     "4.331123" "4.12335435" "1"       
[2,] "1.123453345" "5.654456" "4.889999"   "1.45456" 
[3,] "2.00098"     "5.5445"   "4.768799"   "1.999999"
```

As a result I need a dataframe with values exactly the same as in source file. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As the other answers suggest, reading in your data in the correct format to begin with is the recommended way to deal with this, but for what it's worth, `data.frame(lapply(td, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` should also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `colClasses` in `read.table()` to make all columns as `character`.

```
 td <- read.table("test.csv", sep=',',colClasses="character")
 td
           V1       V2         V3       V4   V5
1     1.12331 4.331123 4.12335435        1  asd
2 1.123453345 5.654456   4.889999  1.45456  qwe
3     2.00098   5.5445   4.768799 1.999999 ttre

 str(td)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "1.12331" "1.123453345" "2.00098"
 $ V2: chr  "4.331123" "5.654456" "5.5445"
 $ V3: chr  "4.12335435" "4.889999" "4.768799"
 $ V4: chr  "1" "1.45456" "1.999999"
 $ V5: chr  "asd" "qwe" "ttre"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is the read the data in as character in the first place. You can do this with the `colClasses` argument to read.table:

```
td <- read.table("test.csv", sep=',', colClasses="character")
```